# "FirefoxDriver cannot be resolved to a type" when running Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The basic code I am using is as follows:

```
Package TestSelenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
public class MyFirstClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com")
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the error

> FirefoxDriver cannot be resolved to a type

I have included all required jars, but still, I am getting this error.

I am using Selenium 3.60:

```
C:\Users\Ankur>javac -version
```

javac 1.8.0_144

Screenshot of all required jars:

[image: Selenium jars]

Answer (score 0):

You need add the below import statement on the top of your page

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
```

it will still throw some exception, because from selenium 3.X on wards you can't directly launch the firefox browser. You need to download browser driver from selenium.hq.org and in your code you need use System.setProperties method or desired capabilities class to specify the location where your browser driver is available.

Comment: Even after changing the code, I am still getting errors:

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TestClass {
 System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\Users\\Ankur\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.19.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
 WebDriver Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 Driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
}

Comment: use this code, it will work ----

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\SeleniumTraining\\BrowserDriver\\geckodriver.exe"); // path for your exe file
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();// Opens the Browser
driver.get("http : //google.com");// opens google page in firefox
System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); // prints the title

Comment: Still getting original issues.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing **`FirefoxDriver cannot be resolved to a type`** says it all. It means the IDE you are using i.e. `Eclipse` is unable to resolve the keyword **`FirefoxDriver`**.

As you can see from the snapshot you shared, the keyword **`FirefoxDriver`** is underlined with a red line which indicates the lack of resolution. The reason for that is we havn't added the required **`import`**. **`FirefoxDriver`** is defined with in **`org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver`**. So we have to import **`org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver`** as well.

Again, if you only add **`org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver`** in your imports still we would face a couple of errors moving a head because we haven't mentioned the location of the **`geckodriver`** binary i.e **`geckodriver.exe`** in our code block. We need to download the **`geckodriver.exe`** from this [location](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and place it in our system and provide the absolute path of the **`geckodriver.exe`** through **`System.setProperty()`** as follows:

```
package TestSelenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class MyFirstClass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_location\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Even after adding above import statement , I am seeing same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding selenium stand alone server(https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) to your project (even though you are using maven), as an external jar and try.
For me this resolution worked.
Right click on your Maven project > Properties > Java Buildpath > Libraries tab Click on Add External jar button > Browse to the folder where the jar is saved > upload >Apply and close